# ASP.NET passing value from textbox to selectcommand with IN vb

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, selectcommand

I have an asp.net webpage with an asp.net  gridview with the following query:

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT * from details2 as t2 WHERE (t2.OCC IN ('+ @txtCOUNTRY +') OR t2.DCC IN ('+ @txtCOUNTRY +')) and t2.ac='Y'"
```

The textbox `txtCOUNTRY` value can have the following values (for example):

> 'AR','ES'

However the parameter `@txtCOUNTRY` doesn't seem to be properly, written as the gridview shows nothing.

if I change it to (for example) it works:

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT * from details2 as t2 WHERE (t2.OCC IN ('AR,'ES') OR t2.DCC IN ('AR','ES')) and t2.ac='Y'"
```

So I can only assume the `@txtCOUNTRY` parameter is incorrectly written.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the values `'AR','ES'` via a SQL parameter, they will automatically be escaped which would make your query literally look for the value: `'AR','ES'`.

See this: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause)

So in your case (since you have a comma separated list of values, each in single quotes):

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT * from details2 as t2 WHERE " &
    "(','+@txtCOUNTRY+',' LIKE '%'','+t2.OCC+''',%' OR ','+@txtCOUNTRY+',' LIKE '%'','+t2.DCC+''',%') " & 
    "and t2.ac='Y'"
```

If you are not enclosing your values in single quotes (for example: `AR,ES`) then the query becomes a bit more readable as you are not having to escape the single quotes in your query:

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT * from details2 as t2 WHERE " &
    "(','+@txtCOUNTRY+',' LIKE '%,'+t2.OCC+',%' OR ','+@txtCOUNTRY+',' LIKE '%,'+t2.DCC+',%') " & 
    "and t2.ac='Y'"
```

**Edit** to provide some clarity as to why this works.

So for example, providing `AR,ES` as the value for the `@txtCOUNTRY` parameter would yield a condition:

```
,AR,ES, LIKE *,[t2.OCC],*   OR   ,AR,ES, LIKE *,[t2.DCC],*
```

This condition would be a match if either `t2.OCC` or `t2.DCC` were either `AR` or `ES` because the pattern would be matched.

This provides a simple way to pass in a comma separated list as a parameter so your query isn't exploitable with a SQL injection.

Comment: ok, I take note about the parameters that can be used. in regards to your example, how is LIKE substituting IN ?

Comment: @user1135218 - I updated the answer to provide some additional details on how this works.